# Getting QR vertices from OpenCV detectAndDecode?

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, qr-code

So I have been trying to get coordinates of the corner in a QR [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpdxA.jpg).

But the output from detectAndDecode functions return some string that looks like "[D@fb258ec".

What have I done wrong? Or is the vertices not meant what I think they mean?

Just starting out on the journey to learn openCV and Android, the process has been though...

Any help or advice is much appreciated, thanks.

A snippet of what I think is the main part is shown below.

Edit 1: Added link to QR and more code.

```
@Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mat1 = inputFrame.gray();
        Mat clrCrr = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mat1, clrCrr, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR);



        QRCodeDetector decoder = new QRCodeDetector();
        Mat QR = new Mat(); //Mat for QR code
        Mat points = new Mat(); // points of QR Mat
        Mat dst = new Mat();    //Output frame

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    Handler h = new Handler();
                    String data = decoder.detectAndDecode(clrCrr, points,QR); //Decode QR
                    EditText editText =  findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    points.convertTo(points,CvType.CV_64FC3);

                    editText.setText("Point 1 " +points.get(0,0) );

                        Log.d("Test", String.valueOf(points.get(0,1)));


                    h.postDelayed(this,3000);
                }
            });



        Imgproc.threshold(mat1, dst, 100, 200, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY); // Threshold and return dst

        return dst
    }
```

Comment: bring a sample image and write those part of related.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.

Just need to use
 `Arrays.toString(points.get(0,0))`
instead of just
 `points.get(0,0)`

This will then return a coordinates like [1142.0, 230.0]